# navigator.notification.alert() is not working in cordova-2.0.0.js?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I am new to phonegap.In my application i want display alerts.For that i have used following code,

```
navigator.notification.alert("PhoneGap is working");
```

But it is not working.My total html code is,

```
    <html>
  <head> 
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script>   

       function inti()
    {
     alert("inti");
     document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);

    }
     function onDeviceReady() {
          alert("on device ready!!!!");
     navigator.notification.alert("PhoneGap is working");
    } 
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="inti()">
    <p id="demo">System date</p>
    <input type="button" onclick="noti()" value="Date" />
  </body>
</html>
```

i got `Cannot call method 'alert' of undefined i got this error` .can any one guide me to over come this issues. Thanks in Advance .....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to add the cordova.js . Try to add this.

`<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>`

also add

`document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);` above `onDeviceReady()` function.

Comment: You should have an init() method that is called on onload then in init() register a listener for "deviceready" then in onDeviceReady() you can do your alerts.

Comment: i have added what u suggested.After adding inti() method onDeviceReady() is not calling....i have added my full code what u suggested please have a look....

Comment: @Chiru is your cordova-2.0.0.js is in assets/js folder .

Comment: working fine just i have added config.xml file in res/xml folder .Thank u so much

Comment: I have also getting same error , I have added xml and js file properly

Answer (score 0):

Check your Cordova Jar file version and you have written in `<script>`. May it'll be different.

Answer (score -1):

navigator.notification.alert( "Yes",
                              callBackFunctionB, // Specify a function to be called
                              'Heading',
                               "OK"
                                );