# navigator.notification.alert fires 4 alerts for 1 call on IOS - jquery mobile - phonegap 2.2.0

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, alert

Not sure whats going on here... but lets say a user enters their PIN and hits a GO button which performs the code below when the PIN is invalid:

```
navigator.notification.alert(
    "Invalid PIN entry. Please try again.",
    alertDismissed,
    "ETA Security",
    ""
);

function alertDismissed(){
    //does nothing
}
```

This works the first time (and repeatedly as long as I dont navigate away and return)... but as I navigate between pages (jquery mobile: everything is on one page [index.html]) and come back to enter another PIN... I call navigator.notification.alert again, but this time, it shows the alert 4 times (5, 6, every time I return to the page, it adds another alert)!

any ideas?

**

**EDIT** - complete example added

**
The user clicks a link that uses ajax to go to the database which returns a json object containing the list.

The database call is an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  type: "POST",
  url: "my url telling the database to return the FIF list JSON object",
  data: sFrmData,
  success: function(ajaxResponse){
      eval(ajaxResponse);
      wait(0);
  }
});
```

The ajax call returns this:

```
  getFifs({"rows":[
           {
        "ID":"12345",
            "CONF":"1",
            "LINK":"http://www.cnn.com",
            "DIS":"My FIF",
            "CONFIRM_CODE":"flightxyz",
            "DESCRIP":"Fif showing blah blah blah"
           }
          ]}
        );
```

In the function getFifs, the CONFIRM BUTTON area below is where the alert is being called (etajs.showAlert(\'Confirm Error\'...)

```
//Build the list of FIFs
function getFifs(oJson){
    //change JQM page to fifs
    $.mobile.changePage("#fifs", "none", false, true);
    var strLi=" ";
    var arrayCnt=0;
    var numTotal=0; 

    $("#listFif").empty();
    strLi+='<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d">';

    $.each(oJson.rows,function(){
      numTotal++;
      var disname=this.DIS;
      var fifid=this.ID;
      var fiflink=this.LINK;
      var descrip=this.DESCRIP;
      var conf=this.CONF;

      strLi+='<li><font size=5>' + disname + '</font><br>';

//******************************************
//CONFIRM BUTTON    
      strLi+='<div data-mini="true" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">';
      strLi+='<a href="#fifCode" onclick="if(fifViewArray['+arrayCnt+']==1){etajs.setIdHolder('+fifid+');"}else{etajs.showAlert(\'Confirm Error\',\'You must first View the FIF before confirming it!\',etajs.alertDismissed);";} ';
      strLi+='data-rel="dialog" data-theme="c" data-role="button">Confirm</a>';
      strLi+='</div>';
      strLi+='<div style="white-space:normal;">Description:<font color=gray> ' + descrip + '</font></div>';
      strLi+='</li>';
    }); //end loop

    strLi+='</ul><Br><Br>';
    $("#listFif").append(strLi).trigger("create");    
    updateScrolling("wrapperFifs"); 
}         

function showAlert(strTitle,strMessage,strCallback){
    navigator.notification.alert(
        strMessage,  // message
        strCallback, // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
        strTitle, // title
        '' // buttonLabels
    );
}

</SCRIPT>



    <!--FIFs Page-->
    <div id="fifs" data-role="page">
        <div id="wrapperFifs" class="iscroll_wrapper"  style="padding-top:0px;">
            <div class="scroller" id="listFif"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because of how jQM works, it is not an error.

If you bind an event on some element or action, each time you revisit that page that event will bind again. So every page reload is one binded even more.

This can be averted like this:

1. If event is bind with .bind( or .on( unbind it before you bind it again with .unbind( or .off( . This is rather bed idea, why bind/unbind whertn you can:
2. Use jQuery Event filter and check if event is bound before you try to bind it. You can find it [here](http://www.codenothing.com/archives/2009/event-filter/).

Example:

$('#button:Event(!click)').each(function(){
       // button don't have bound click event, bind it now
   });

Another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477772/navigator-notification-alert-is-not-working-in-cordova-2-0-0-js), 2 for 1:

```
$('document:Event(!deviceready)').each(function(){
    $('#button').unbind();
    $('#button').bind('click', function(e) {
         navigator.notification.alert("PhoneGap is working");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, Gajotres! I am fairly new to JQM... I wonder if you could spoon-feed me a bit with how to do this? navigator.notification.alert is a phonegap thing... how would I unbind or "clear-out" any previous instances of it each time before I try to display the alert?

Comment: NOTE: my main page, index.html NEVER gets reloaded itself. All navigation is JQM and ajax calls

Comment: It is enough to change page and go back, another event will be binded

Comment: Look at this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477772/navigator-notification-alert-is-not-working-in-cordova-2-0-0-js , alert is shown on deviceready event, I will update my answer with an example

Comment: THANKS VERY MUCH FOR YOUR HELP!!!    I'm afraid I still don't get it... do you know anything about phonegap? can you show me an example using navigator.notification.alert()? I am not looking to unbind/bind a single button click... the entire framework uses navigator.notification.alert... I need a way to either destroy any existing instances before trying to call navigator.notification.alert again... ***** before I call navigator.notification.alert, I need some way to destroy previous instance of it (or check to see if it is already present... then how to send message to it?)...

Answer (score 2):

Where are you attaching the click handler? If it is set on pageshow or as a delegated event in page create, you can end up with duplicated handlers.

Either moving the event binding code or returning false so only one runs should fix it

Comment: numeraous ways... here is one:
`code
<a href="#" onclick="showAlert();" data-rel="dialog" data-theme="c" data-role="button">CONFIRM</a>

function showAlert(){
   navigator.notification.alert(
 'You must first View the FIF before confirming it!', 
 alertDismissed, 
 'Confirm Error',
 ''
  );
}


function alertDismissed(){
    //does nothing
}`

Comment: That method can't cause duplicates, must be one of the other numerous ways. The code snippets you show are fine, it's where they fit into the overall structure of the app that is causing problems.

Comment: I edited my original post to show the complete example. Thanks for your help, Tom!

Comment: Declaring the shoe function inline in onclick is very error prone - I think you have some mismatched quotes there. Try to keep the on click attribute to a simple function call with one or two parameters.

Comment: Thanks Tom. however, I tried using a function call in the link instead with the following code and still get multiple alerts:`code ...
strLi+='<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="checkFif(fifViewArray['+arrayCnt+']);" data-rel="dialog" data-theme="c" data-role="button">Confirm</a>';

function checkFif(read){
    if(read==1){
     $.mobile.changePage('#fifPinEntry','flip', false, true);
     $('#fifconfirmpinsingle').val('');
    }else{
     etajs.showalertReset=0;
     etajs.showAlert('Confirm Error','You must first View the FIF before confirming it!',etajs.alertDismissed);
    } 
}`help! ;)

Answer (score 1):

ok! finally!!! I can't believe it... so here is how I fixed it. I changed the anchor in my list to an input type=button with onclick...

here is the dynamic list view item before:

```
strLi+='<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-rel="dialog" data-role="button">Confirm</a>';
```

And this is the link click setup (I tried this EVERY way possible but this is just one. I also tried an onclick right in the anchor)

```
$('.fifconfbut').live('click', function() {
    checkFif(); //This function call fires multiple times upon returning to the page
    return(false);
});
```

And the working code!

```
strLi+='<input onclick="checkFif();" type=button data-rel="dialog" data-role="button" value="Confirm">';



//This is the function that gets called when the item is clicked
function checkFif(){
    etajs.showAlert('Confirm Error','blah blah blah',etajs.alertDismissed);
    return(false);

}
```

What I would like to know is why does an anchor fire multiple click events but the button does not?